# How to return a pure value from a impure method

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I know it must sound trivial but I was wondering how you can unwrap a value from a functor and return it as pure value?

I have tried:

```
f::IO a->a
f x=(x>>=) 

f= >>=
```

What should I place in the right side? I can't use `return` since it will wrap it back again.

Comment: You don't. The entire idea of this is that it forces to chain operations. You can thus write a function that takes an `a`, and returns an `IO b`, and so chain them together with `(>>=)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22063216/67579

Comment: You can't do that from `IO` monad. Take an RNG for an example why.

Comment: If your procedure executes an action which is IO then your procedure is itself IO and the type must reflect that fact.

Comment: Even using [unsafe `IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html), `f` isn't pure, because you can't predict the return value of, for example, `f getLine`.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214664/haskell-trapped-in-io-monad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a frequently asked question: *How do I extract 'the' value from my monad*, not only in Haskell, but in other languages as well. I have a theory about why this question keeps popping up, so I'll try to answer according to that; I hope it helps.

## Containers of single values

You can think of a *functor* (and therefore also a *monad*) as a **container** of values. This is most palpable with the (redundant) `Identity` functor:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Identity> Identity 42
Identity 42
```

This is nothing but a wrapper around a value, in this case `42`. For this particular container, you *can* extract the value, because it's guaranteed to be there:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Identity> runIdentity $ Identity 42
42
```

While `Identity` seems fairly useless, you can find other functors that seem to wrap a single value. In F#, for example, you'll often encounter containers like `Async<'a>` or `Lazy<'a>`, which are used to represent asynchronous or lazy computations (Haskell doesn't need the latter, because it's lazy by default).

You'll find lots of other single-value containers in Haskell, such as `Sum`, `Product`, `Last`, `First`, `Max`, `Min`, etc. Common to all of those is that they wrap a single value, which means that you *can* extract the value.

I think that when people first encounter functors and monads, they tend to think of the concept of a *data container* in this way: as a container of a single value.

## Containers of optional values

Unfortunately, some common monads in Haskell seem to support that idea. For example, `Maybe` is a data container as well, but one that can contain zero or one value. You can, unfortunately, still extract the value if it's there:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe> fromJust $ Just 42
42
```

The problem with this is that `fromJust` isn't *total*, so it'll crash if you call it with a `Nothing` value:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe> fromJust Nothing
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

You can see the same sort of problem with `Either`. Although I'm not aware of a built-in partial function to extract a `Right` value, you can easily write one with pattern matching (if you ignore the compiler warning):

```
extractRight :: Either l r -> r
extractRight (Right x) = x
```

Again, it works in the 'happy path' scenario, but can just as easily crash:

```
Prelude> extractRight $ Right 42
42
Prelude> extractRight $ Left "foo"
*** Exception: <interactive>:12:1-26: Non-exhaustive patterns in function extractRight
```

Still, since functions like `fromJust` exists, I suppose it tricks people new to the concept of functors and monads into thinking about them as data containers from which you can extract a value.

When you encounter something like `IO Int` for the first time, then, I can understand why you'd be tempted to think of it as a container of a single value. In a sense, it is, but in another sense, it isn't.

## Containers of multiple values

Even with lists, you can (attempt to) extract 'the' value from a list:

```
Prelude> head [42..1337]
42
```

Still, it could fail:

```
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

At this point, however, it should be clear that attempting to extract 'the' value from any arbitrary functor is nonsense. A list is a functor, but it contains an arbitrary number of values, including zero and infinitely many.

What you *can* always do, though, is to write functions that take a 'contained' value as input and returns another value as output. Here's an arbitrary example of such a function:

```
countAndMultiply :: Foldable t => (t a, Int) -> Int
countAndMultiply (xs, factor) = length xs * factor
```

While you can't 'extract *the* value' out of a list, you can apply your function to each of the values in a list:

```
Prelude> fmap countAndMultiply [("foo", 2), ("bar", 3), ("corge", 2)]
[6,9,10]
```

Since `IO` is a functor, you can do the same with it as well:

```
Prelude> foo = return ("foo", 2) :: IO (String, Int)
Prelude> :t foo
foo :: IO (String, Int)
Prelude> fmap countAndMultiply foo
6
```

The point is that you don't extract a value from a functor, **you step into the functor**.

## Monad

Sometimes, the function you apply to a functor returns a value that's already wrapped in the same data container. As an example, you may have a function that splits a string over a particular character. To keep things simple, let's just look at the built-in function `words` that splits a string into words:

```
Prelude> words "foo bar"
["foo","bar"]
```

If you have a list of strings, and apply `words` to each, you'll get a nested list:

```
Prelude> fmap words ["foo bar", "baz qux"]
[["foo","bar"],["baz","qux"]]
```

The result is a nested data container, in this case a list of lists. You can flatten it with `join`:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> join $ fmap words ["foo bar", "baz qux"]
["foo","bar","baz","qux"]
```

This is the original definition of a monad: it's a functor that you can flatten. In modern Haskell, `Monad` is defined by *bind* (`>>=`), from which one can derive `join`, but it's also possible to derive `>>=` from `join`.

## IO as all values

At this point, you may be wondering: *what does that have to do with `IO`?* Isn't `IO a` a container of a single value of the type `a`?

Not really. One *interpretation* of `IO` is that it's a container that holds an arbitrary value of the type `a`. According to that interpretation, it's analogous to the *many-worlds* interpretation of quantum mechanics. `IO a` is the superposition of all possible values of the type `a`.

In Schrödinger's original thought experiment, the cat in the box is both alive and dead until observed. That's two possible states superimposed. If we think about a variable called `catIsAlive`, it would be equivalent to the superposition of `True` and `False`. So, you can think of `IO Bool` as a set of possible values `{True, False}` that will only collapse into a single value when observed.

Likewise, `IO Word8` can be interpreted as a superposition of the set of all possible `Word8` values, i.e. `{0, 1, 2,.. 255}`, `IO Int` as the superposition of all possible `Int` values, `IO String` as all possible `String` values (i.e. an infinite set), and so on.

So how do you *observe* the value, then?

You don't extract it, you work *within* the data container. You can, as shown above, `fmap` and `join` over it. So, you can write your application as pure functions that you then compose with impure values with `fmap`, `>>=`, `join`, and so on.

Comment: Wow thank you for the explanation.Yours and @trevor cooks really gave me a better view on this topic.My thought process was wrong then.I was considering `>>=` similar to C# `Task<T>` where you can unwrap the value by using the `await` keyword and from that point you can use the extracted value.Although when you say "we get inside the functor" it means that having something like `m a->(a-> m b)->b` we  "enter the m a functor" and by applying the `(a-> mb)` we enter the `m b functor` ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian C#'s `await` keyword is just syntactic sugar, similar to Haskell's 
`<-` binding inside of `do` notation. They're pretty close, although `Task<T>` isn't a monad. The *step into the functor* analogy is imprecise at best; it was an attempt at making the concepts easier to understand. If I didn't succeed at that, then don't sweat it. What I meant, though, is that you can 'inject' your pure functions into your `IO` values, using `fmap`, `>>=`, and so on. This sort of lets you perform work inside the container, without ever having to extract the data. HTH.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian a typo in your comment: you meant `m a->(a-> m b)->m b`, where we "enter the `m a` monad" and by applying the `(a-> m b)` function *on the inside* we turn `m a` into `m b` monad, that will process the `a` from the `m a` with `a->m b`. why "monad" and not just "functor"? for functor it's `m a->(a-> b)->m b`; and so with `a-> m b` used with `m a` as a *functor*, it's `m a->(a->m b)->m (m b)`; and putting *that* result through the monad's *`join`*, we finally get the `m b`. why do we want `m a -> ... -> m b`? for *compositionality*, to build chains `m a ->...->m b->...->m c->...`

Answer (score 4):

It is trivial, so this will be a long answer. In short, the problem lies in the signature, `IO a -> a`, is not a type properly allowed in Haskell. This really has less to do with `IO` being a functor than the fact that `IO` is special.

For some functors you can recover the pure value. For instance a partially applied pair, `(,) a`, is a functor. We unwrap the value via `snd`.

```
snd :: (a,b) -> b
snd (_,b) = b
```

So this is a functor that we can unwrap to a pure value, but this really has nothing to do with being a functor. It has more to do with pairs belonging to a different Category Theoretic concept, [Comonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/Control-Comonad.html), with:

```
extract :: Comonad w => w a -> a
```

Any `Comonad` will be a functor for which you can recover the pure value.

Many (non-comonadic) functors have--lets say "evaluators"--which allow something like what is being asked. For instance, we can evaluate a `Maybe` with `maybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`. By providing a default, `maybe a` has the desired type, `Maybe a -> a`. Another useful example from [State](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html), `evalState :: State s a -> s -> a`, has its arguments reversed but the concept is the same; given the monad, `State s a`, and initial state, `s`, we unwrap the pure value, `a`.

Finally to the specifics of `IO`. No "evaluator" for `IO` is provided in the Haskell language or libraries. We might consider running the program itself an evaluator--much in the same vein of `evalState`. But if that's a valid conceptual move, then it should only help to convince you that there is no sane way to unwrap from `IO`--any program written is just the `IO a` input to its evaluator function.

Instead, what you are forced to do--**by design**--is to work within the `IO` monad. For instance, if you have a pure function, `f :: a -> b`, you apply it within the `IO` context via, `fmap f :: IO a -> IO b`

**TL;DR** You can't get a pure value out of the `IO` monad. Apply pure functions within the `IO` context, for instance by `fmap`