# How does the operator <- in haskell behave?

Tags: haskell, do-notation

I understand (somewhat) monads and understand that the operator <- will extract the value from the monad.

But how does it work with different types?

Typically, I have seen it being used to extract strings from IO monad. But in the example code below am not able to see why it fails in main 3rd line, complaining that it is expecting a type of IO int? How is the compiler infering that an IO int is needed?

Also what does it (`<-`) do in the `multWithLog` method?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy

main = do
   putStrLn $ show $ logNumber 3 -- prints WriterT (Identity (3,["Got Number: 3"]))
   putStrLn $ show $ multWithLog -- prints WriterT (Identity (3,["Got Number: 3"]))
    _ <- logNumber 3 -- fails with Couldn't match type ‘WriterT [String] Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’ with ‘IO’
                    -- Expected type: IO Int
                    -- Actual type: Writer [String] Int
   putStrLn "test"


logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
logNumber x = writer (x, ["Got Number: " ++ show x])

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int
multWithLog = do
  a <- logNumber 3
  --b <- logNumber 5
  return a
```

Comment: all the values to the right of `<-` in the same `do` block must be of type `Monad m => m _`, for the same `m`.

Comment: Thanks all, I guess where I was tripping again and again was forgetting that the bind takes a method which will take a normal value (from within monad m) and then it needs to wrap it back (after processing) in the same type of monad m. In my mind I sort of forgot <- is a syntactic shortcut for bind and was thinking as if <- is more of a haskell operator which "extracts" some value (as per the context of monad) and leaves me free to do what I want with this normal value (which is not correct, since I am bound to call a method which has the constraint to  return the result in wrapped in moand m.

Comment: the point here is that you are extracting them from the *same* monad each time, while in the *same* `do` block. so trying to extract from different monads in the same `do` block doesn't work. *that* was your problem here, not what you wrote above. also, it's not always *you* that "wraps" the value; sometimes - like you have in your code, too - you are using a primitive of a given monad, like `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`, that returns a monadic action value all by itself. this "wrapping" thing is not a good metaphor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every statement in a `do` block must be from the same monadic type.

In

```
multWithLog = do
  a <- logNumber 3
  return a
```

we have `logNumber 3 :: Writer [String] Int` and `return a :: (Monad m) => m Int` (which is polymorphic), so the whole thing typechecks as `Writer [String] Int` (with `m = Writer [String]`, which is a monad).

In

```
main = do
   putStrLn $ show $ logNumber 3
   putStrLn $ show $ multWithLog
    _ <- logNumber 3
   putStrLn "test"
```

we have `putStrLn ... :: IO ()` and `logNumber 3 :: Writer [String] Int`. This is a type error because `Writer [String]` is not the same as `IO`.

The underlying reason is that `do` blocks are just syntactic sugar for calls to `>>=` and `>>`. E.g. your `main` really means

```
main =
   (putStrLn $ show $ logNumber 3) >>
   (putStrLn $ show $ multWithLog) >>
   logNumber 3 >>= \_ ->
   putStrLn "test"
```

with

```
(>>)  :: (Monad m) => m a -> m b -> m b
(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

which requires the type `m` to remain the same throughout.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with wording such as

> extract the value from the monad

A monad doesn't contain 'a' value. For example, `Maybe` contains zero or one value. List (`[]`) contains multiple values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620647/126014) for more details.

In the list case, for example, the `<-` operator extracts *each* of the list values, one at a time.

When you use `do` notation, all values extracted must belong to the same `Monad`. In the OP, the compiler infers that the `Monad` in question is `IO`, since `putStrLn` returns `IO ()` values.

`logNumber`, on the other hand, returns `Writer [String] Int` values, and while that's also a `Monad` instance, it's not the same as `IO`. Therefore, the code doesn't type check.

Comment: @WillNess I don't object to the word *extract*; I warn again the articles *the* and *a*.

Comment: I'm referring to the different sentence, this one: "all values extracted must belong to the same Monad"

Comment: @WillNess Ah, would it be more correct to say that *all values extracted must originate from the same Monad?* Or something like that...

Comment: maybe "all Monadic action values (those to the right of `<-`, or on a line of their own) must belong to the same Monad".

Answer (score 1):

Kepping things simple. These are two facts

1. `Writer [String]` is actually monad, so `Writer [String] Int` can be seen as `m Int`
2. Every action in a `do` block should happen within the same monad.

In the `main` function the compiler is reasoning as follows:

1. I am working within the `IO` monad since `putStrLn ...` is of type `IO ()`
2. Let me compute `_ <- logNumber 3`. Since I am in the `IO` monad, `logNumber 3` should be `IO WhatEver`
3. `logNumber 3` is actually a monadic value of type `m Int`
4. Wait! `m` is the `Writer [String]` monad, not the `IO` monad
5. Print an error saying that `Writer [String] Int` is incorrect an It should be `IO Int`

So that is where `IO Int` comes from. I am just triying to be pedagogic here. Check @melpomene's answer for a complete explanation

Hope it helps.