# How to generate datatypes that use MVars?

Tags: haskell, generator, quickcheck

I have a datatype that looks like this:

```hs
data PageLogCommand = LogPage Page
                    | Stop (MVar ())
```

And I want to create a generator of type `Gen PageLogCommand`.

For the `Stop` command though, making a new empty MVar has type `IO (MVar a)`, so how can I get the `MVar` out of the `IO` monad and use it to make a `Gen` type?

Answer (score 2):

How about passing the `MVar` as a parameter to your `Gen` function? Like

```hs
pageLogCommandGen :: MVar () -> Gen PageLogCommand
pageLogCommandGen stopMVar = oneof
  [ LogPage <$> arbitrary
  , pure (Stop stopMVar)
  ]
```

Then you can generate `stopMVar` in IO and pass it on like

```hs
do stopMVar <- newEmptyMVar
   plc <- generate (pageLogCommandGen stopMVar)
   ...
```

before you test a property.

Answer (score 0):

You [can't extract a pure value from `IO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620647/126014). That's by design.

You can, however, write QuickCheck properties that run in `IO`; something like this:

```
myIOProperty :: Testable prop => IO prop
myIOProperty = do
  mvar <- newEmptyMVar
  -- do something with mvar here and return a result
```

Then use `ioProperty` or `idempotentIOProperty` to turn the `IO prop` value into a `Property`.