# Is it possible to use writeFile inside out of the main function (in haskell)?

Tags: haskell

I am still a beginner in Haskell, so after reading some `writefile` tutorials online, I see most of the `writefile` examples online are used inside the `main` function (main = IO ())

I am wondering whether it's possible to write a function that writes the results into a file using `writefile` when it is computed? In some programs (especially games), users might want to stop at a particular points of the game by saving the contents into a .txt file.

For example something like this: (this function does not work, just wondering how to make it work)

```
concat :: FilePath -> [[a]] -> [a]
concat txt [] = []`
concat txt (xs : xss) = do
y <- xs ++ concat xss
writeFile txt (unlines y)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: You can not use `writeFile` here since that has type `String -> String -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 9):

The `writeFile` function has the type `FilePath -> String -> IO ()`, which means that it must run in the `IO` context.

It doesn't *have* to run in the `main` function, but any function that involves `IO`, including `writeFile`, will have a return type that involves `IO`. So you could definitely do something like this:

```
myFunc :: String -> IO ()
myFunc contents = do
  -- do something else
  writeFile "foo.txt" contents
  -- do more stuff here
```

You can't, however, call functions that return `IO a` from pure functions (or, rather, [you can't extract the value from the IO container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620647/126014)). That's by design; it's how Haskell works, and [it's a good thing](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/19/functional-architecture-a-definition). If you want to enable users to perform impure actions at arbitrary times, you must design for such a feature. [Here's my introduction to pure interactions](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/07/10/pure-interactions) - that's one place to start.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use `writeFile` in other places than `main`, but for a place to qualify, the type `IO` has to be a part of that place's type signature. (The reason I'm saying *place* is because `main` isn't a function, but your `concat` *is* a function. And the place you want to look at putting your `writeFile` call has to be an `IO` *action*, which can be the result of a function or not.)

You mentioned saving something related to a game into a .txt file. An example of that could be:

```hs
saveGame :: FilePath -> GameState -> IO ()
saveGame gameFile gameState =
  writeFile gameFile (serializeGame gameState)

serializeGame :: GameState -> String
serializeGame (GameState ...) = ...

runGame :: GameState -> IO ()
runGame gameState = do
  ...
  if wantsToSaveGame
    then saveGame gameFile gameState
    else ...
  ...
  runGame updatedGameState

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ...
  runGame initialGameState
```

In this contrived example, `serializeGame` would not be a suitable place to call `saveGame` because it's a pure function, whereas `runGame` is a self-recursive `IO ()` action capable of affecting files on your file system.

An example of a related `IO` action that *isn't* a function could be this one:

```hs
resetSaveGame :: IO ()
resetSaveGame =
  saveGame defaultGameFile initialGameState
```