# What does it mean to "run" inside a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, purely-functional

Working through Haskell textbook chapters on different monads, I repeatedly get lost when the authors jump from explaining the details of *bind* and the monad laws to actually using monads. Suddenly, expressions like "running a function in a monadic context", or "to run a monad" pop up. Similarly, in library documentation and in discussions about monad transformer stacks, I read statements that some function "can be run in any choice of monad". What does this "running inside a monad" exactly mean?

There are two things I don't seem to get straight:

1. A monad is a type class with functions (`return`, `>>=`) and laws. To "run" something inside a monad could thus either mean (a) to provide it as argument to `return`, or (b) to sequence it using `>>=`. If the monad is of type `m a`, then in case a) that *something* must be of type `a`, to match the type of the `return` function. In case b) that *something* must be a function of type `a -> m b`, to match the type of the `>>=` function. From this, I do not understand how I can "run" some function inside an arbitrary monad, because the functions I sequence using `>>=` must all have the same type signature, and the values I lift using `return` must be of the specific monad type parameter.
2. In my understanding, there is no notion of *execution* or *running* a computation in a functional language - there is only function application to some argument, and evaluating the function (replacing it with its value). Yet, many specific monads come with a `run` function such as `runReader`, `runState`, etc. These functions are not part of the definition of a monad, and they are plain functions, not in any way special imperative statements outside the functional core of the language. So, what do they "run"?

I feel that having a clear understanding of these concepts is key to understanding monad transformer stacks or similar constructs that seem to be necessary to understand any substantial libraries and any non-trivial programs in Haskell. Thanks very much for helping me to make the leap from simply writing functional code to actually understanding what it means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authors who write books and articles often use metaphors and less precise language when they try to explain concepts. The purpose is to give the reader a conceptual intuition for what's going on.

I believe that the concept of 'running' a function falls into this category. Apart from `IO`, you're right that the functions you use to compose, say, `[]`, `Maybe`, and so on are no special from other functions.

The notion of running something inside of a monad comes, I think, from the observation that [functors are containers](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/01/14/functors-are-containers). This observation applies to monads as well, since all monads are functors. `[Bool]` is a container of Boolean values, `Maybe Int` is a container of (zero or one) numbers. You can even think of the reader functor `r -> a` as a container of `a` values, because you can imagine that it's just a very big lookup table.

Being able to 'run a function inside a container' is useful because not all containers enable access to their contents. Again, `IO` is the prime example, since it's an opaque container.

A frequently asked question is: [How to return a pure value from a impure method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51614573/126014). Likewise, many beginners ask: How do I get the value of a `Maybe`? You could even ask: How do I get the value out of a list? Generalised, the question becomes: [How to get the value out of the monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/04/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-the-monad).

The answer is that you don't. You 'run the function inside the container', or, as I like to put it, you [inject the behaviour into the monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/04/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-the-monad/#f2fd9c0c72fd45ea86908edb606740b6). You never leave the container, but rather let your functions execute within the context of it. Particularly when it comes to `IO`, this is the only way you can interact with that container, because it's otherwise opaque (I'm here pretending that `unsafePerformIO` doesn't exist).

Keep in mind when it comes to the *bind* method (`>>=`) that while the function 'running inside of it' has the type `a -> m b`, you can also 'run' a 'normal' function `a -> b` inside the monad with `fmap`, because all `Monad` instances are also `Functor` instances.

Comment: How to get a value out of a monad: In my understanding, this is not an issue about the monad as such, but if the module, in which the type that has an instance of the monad type class is defined, exposes the types data constructor or not. If it does, I can pattern-match on it and extract the value wrapped inside that type. When using `>>=`, I don't need that pattern matching, because it's implicitly done inside `>>=`.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster It's true that this isn't an issue of the monad *abstraction*, but of particular monads (again, notably: `IO`). It's not a question of whether the data constructors are exported, though. Both `[]`, `Maybe`, and `Either e` export their data constructors. How do you get *the* value out of any of those?

Comment: Well, there is not necessarily one value, as you point out in your blog post https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/04/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-the-monad/. But as long as I can pattern-match on data constructors, I can mess around with the implementation of the type. That's why I'm also trying to get a better understanding of abstract data types in Haskell (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61638297/best-practice-for-using-abstract-data-types-in-haskell).

Comment: @UlrichSchuster Yes, you can certainly pattern-match on the data constructors of `[]`, `Maybe`, `Either e`, etc. but then you have to cover all cases by manually writing the code that deals with each case. `fmap` and `>>=` gives you convenient ways to compose smaller functions within the container in question. This may be particularly clear with `Either e`, where you get to ignore the `Left` case when you want to focus on the happy path of your code.

Answer (score 1):

> the functions I sequence using >>= must all have the same type signature

This is only sorta true. In some monadic context, we may have the expression

```
x >>= f >>= g
```

where

```
x :: Maybe Int
f :: Int -> Maybe String
g :: String -> Maybe Char
```

All of these must involve the same monad (Maybe), but note that they do not all have the same type signature. Just as with ordinary function composition, you don't need all the return types to be the same, merely that the input of one function match up with the output of its predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple analogy of "run the function inside the container", with pseudocode:

Let's say you have some type Future[String] which represents a container that will have a string "at some time in the future":

```
val tweet: Future[String] = getTweet()
```

Now you want to access the string -- but you do not take the string out of the context -- the "future" -- you simply use the string "inside the container":

```
tweet.map { str =>
  println(str)
}
```

Inside these curly braces, you are "in the future". For example:

```
val tweet: Future[String] = getTweet()

tweet.map { str =>
  println(str)
}

println("Length of tweet string is " + tweet.length) // <== WRONG -- you are not yet in the future
```

The tweet.length is trying to access the tweet *outside of the container*. So "being inside the container" is analogous to, when reading the source code, "being inside the curly braces of a map (flatmap, etc.)". You are dipping inside of the container.

```
tweet.map { str =>
  println("Length of tweet string is " + str.length) // <== RIGHT
}
```

Albeit a very simple analogy, I find this useful when thinking of all monads in general. In the source code, where is one "inside the container" and where is one outside? In this case, the length function is running in the future, or "inside the container".